# Static file configuration is not working in my project

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm working with "Web Development with Django" book where I'm building bookr project. It is a web page that shows books, their reviews and ratings.
I am on chapter 5, where main thing that I am supposed to do is to add logo image to my page using static file serving and block brand.

My main base.html in templates directory has everything required to call static image from another html file
directory: bookr/templates/base.html

```
{% load static %}
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{% block brand %}Book Review{% endblock %}</a>
```

Another base.html has block brand
directory: bookr/reviews/templates/reviews/base.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block brand %}<img src="{% static 'static/logoo.png' %}">{% endblock %}
```

the logo image is in this directory: bookr/reviews/static/logoo.png (it is not corrupted and working perfectly well)

the setting.py for templates looks like this

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and finally the view.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "base.html")
```

[image: the page is loading without changes done to html file]

Comment: `I tried to make the whole page red` none of shown code tries to do anything _red_. It makes hard to understand what was expected and what is wrong with current implementation. Please rephrase your question, make your description more specific. `any changes on html are not working` do you mean only CSS and images? Do you see changes when you modify text in the template?

Comment: It smells like your question is actually about static files configuration.

Comment: `I tried to make the whole page red` it is working now. It was simple mistake, I thought it was related to my main problem. My only problem now is with static image configuration. I still cannot configure my static logo image.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your main urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('example.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL,  document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And Add this code to your settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    BASE_DIR / 'reviews/static',# in your case "bookr/reviews/static/logoo.png"
]
```

May be it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).